# Negativa alternatives when the knee can't bend as far

Tags: technique, capoeira

A common *esquiva*, and bridging movement, in Capoeira is the *negativa* (in this case, the *regional* version) where you you have your weight primarily on the ball of one foot, directly underneath your buttocks, with your knee fully bent, with the other leg extended in front of you. Recently, my left knee has been acting up, hurting when I bend it past about 135 degrees, which makes *negativa* painful. In class, I've been trying to do it higher on the one side, and concentrate more on upright dodges during the *roda*, but I don't always remember to do so in the heat of the moment. Is there a good movement for me to substitute in for, say, *role* for entering and exiting while dodging a kick, at least until my knee is back up to snuff?

Comment: I'll just say the obvious thing is to take a break from training until your knee heals. Aside from that, let's suppose this is real life self-defense, and you have a bad knee. What do you do? If your mobility and flexibility is a problem, you're better off closing the distance and getting within your opponent's inside fighting range. That way, you can remain upright and won't need to be as mobile. Get in close and stick to your opponent. Put your weight on your good leg and then go for a throw or a take-down. But that's generic advice, not capoeira.